# Linq to SQL generates a string comparison

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Given the following classes,

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; } //mapped to column 'property'
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; } //mapped to table dbo.MyClasses
}
```

I'm trying to generate the following SQL request, using Linq to SQL and EF Core 3.1.

```sql
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyClasses
WHERE property > 'constant'
```

Any help appreciated.

---

Attempt 1:

```cs
var result = dbContext.MyClasses.Where(c => c.Property > "constant").ToList();

//Does not compile
```

Attempt 2:

```cs
var result = dbContext.MyClasses.Where(c => c.Property.CompareTo("constant") > 0).ToList();

//SELECT * FROM dbo.MyClasses
//WHERE
//CASE                                                
//  WHEN property  = 'constant' THEN 0  
//  WHEN property  > 'constant' THEN 1  
//  WHEN property  < 'constant' THEN -1    
//END > 0
```

Comment: Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, and EF Core 3 are all **different things**. Please remove the two incorrect tags (i.e. keep EF Core only). Please remove 'LINQ to SQL' terminology from the question also.

Comment: The Attempt 2 doesn't produce the same results, even if the SQL is different?

Comment: The main problem is that `string `data type does not define comparison operators, so you have to use `string.Compare` or `string.CompareTo` methods, which currently have no good SQL translation. Either accept the current inefficient translation and wait RF Core to improve it eventually in some future version, or use the solution/workaround from my answer to the post marked as "duplicate".

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use raw SQL:

```
var id = 1;
dbContext.MyClasses
    .FromSqlInterpolated("SELECT * FROM dbo.MyClasses WHERE property > {id}")
    .ToList<MyClass>();
```

It is possible to read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

Comment: `new SqlParameter("@id", 1)` creates a parameter whose SqlDbType parameter is 1 (Binary) without any value. Enums are essentially tagged integers so `SqlParameter (string, System.Data.SqlDbType)` is a better match for this call than `SqlParameter(string,Object)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the great comment. I've updated my answer with a little bit another solution. Thanks!

Comment: In EF Core 3.x it should be [FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). You can write `.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.MyClasses WHERE property > @id", id)` now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank a lot, I've updated an answer!:)